# Agrupar por data num campo timestamp

Tags: php, mysql

Como consigo agrupar os dados vindos do MYSQL por data, sendo que no BD o campo e Timestamp **2019-04-18 08:01:10**

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_reclamacoes GROUP BY data_reclamacoes ORDER BY data_reclamacoes ASC";
```

Comment: não faz muito sentido essa consulta, o que você quer agrupar (quais campos deveriam ser listados)?

Comment: No banco tenho varias datas no mesmo dia, porem em horários diferentes,
Se dou um GROUP BY na data, ele so ira me mostrar os que forem igual, com a mesma data e hora, no caso eu preciso que me agrupe todos da mesma data, ignorando o horário

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize a função `Date`, da seguinte maneira:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_reclamacoes GROUP BY DATE(data_reclamacoes) ORDER BY data_reclamacoes ASC";
```

Ela irá trazer somente a data no momento de agrupar.

Answer (score 0):

Considerando a ideia de trazer as ocorrências na mesma data, ignorando o horário, acredito que a consulta deva ficar assim:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_reclamacoes
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(data_reclamacoes, "%M %d %Y") = DATE_FORMAT(data_pesquisada, "%M %d %Y")
ORDER BY data_reclamacoes ASC
```

Considerando que a `data_pesquisada` será a do dia a ser consultado.